# Calling observer.next() on Observable<void> in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am creating a module that uses RxJS Observable and some of the methods are returning `Observable<void>`. I have searched around quite a bit now, but can't find any best practices on completion of `Observable<void>`.

So the question is simple, should the `next` callback be issued for these observables, or just the `complete` callback?

In my opinion it seems to be cleanest to only call `complete`, but `Observable<T>.subscribe()` has `complete` as it last parameter, which makes it more complicated for users to use.

Take this code example as an illustration of the question:

```
doSomethingIgnorableUnlessError(): Observable<void> {
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<void>) => {
    if (executeIgnorable()) {
      // should observer.next(null); be called here?
      observer.next(null); 
      observer.complete();
    } else {
      observer.error('something that shouldn't be ignored occurred');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it depends on the use case.  `Observable<void>` is just a stream of zero or more signals that have no actual data in them.  There's nothing wrong with an observable<void> that produces a whole lot of next calls to signal that "something happened".  You just won't get any information within your next callback (other than the fact that your callback got triggered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Observable` is meant to be used when you want to respond to a potentially changing stream of data. Your function above, `doSomethingIgnoreUnlessError()` will return to you an observable, to which you can `.subscribe()` with a callback function; that function will execute every time the Observable calls `.next()`. In the case of `Observable<void>` you can just omit the data payload function argument in the subscribe callback like so:

```
doSomethingIgnorableUnlessError().subscribe(() => {
    // do something; without data it's just an event
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error condition from returned Observable
});
```

Ultimately you need to call `.next()` at least once so that any subscribers to that observable receive the event and fire the `.subscribe()`. The use of `.complete()` produces a different event that can be hooked to from the returned Observable, and doesn't support passing any data; so it's more or less an Event you respond to.

We can illustrate and simplify this using the optional parameters of the `.subscribe()` method, like so:

```
doSomethingIgnorableUnlessError().subscribe(() => {
    // do something; without data it's just an event
}, err => {
    // handle error condition from returned Observable
}, () => {
    // handle subscription complete (no more data coming)
});
```

That captures all three - the subscription data, errors, and the completion event. 
If you never call `.next()` within the observable, the subscription callback (first param) never fires and it's somewhat unintuitive to write an Observable that ONLY sends a completion event. If that's what you need and you HAVE to use an Observable, it's advisable to convert it into a Promise which is always single-use. There's even a built in `.toPromise()` for one such an occasion!

So **TL;DR** - it doesn't matter if you pass `null` to `.next()` if you're ignoring the data being passed into the `.subscribe()` of your returned Observable, and you only call `.complete()` by hand in your Observable if you wish to terminate the stream of data and cancel all subscriptions. If your Observable will ever need to Push another change value, don't call `.complete()`!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you confirmed my suspicions in the section where you described it's unintuitive to not call .next()!

Answer (score 6):

Personally, my approach is that if you have `Observable<void>` it means it emits but its values don't matter. You can still call `next()` but to make it obvious that you're not passing any value you should use `void 0`:

```
subject.next(void 0);
```

Then consuming this Subject is like any other Observable where you just ignore the value itself:

```
subject.subscribe(() => ...);
```

What's important here is that this is not the same as using `null` or `undefined`. You can have for example `Observable<number>` and call `observer.next(null)` or `observer.next(undefined)` (https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-jtwymx?file=index.ts) even though it doesn't make sense. You want a `number` but if you receive `undefined` you might experience weird behavior. For example `undefined + 4` is `NaN`.

I think a typical use-case for `Observable<void>` is infinite scroll. When you scroll to the end of a page you want to load more data so you call `subject.next(void 0)` where it's obvious that the value doesn't matter. It's only used to trigger loading more items.

Comment: FYI `void 0 === undefined`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void